# How to give a unique constraint to a combination of columns in SQL irrespective of Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a two tables.  First One is the product table that hold the Data and the second one holds the  Parent Child relationship.

```
ProductTable
===================
PkId Manufacturer Model ...
1      A            A1
2      B            B1
3      C            C1

JoinIng Table for Parent Child relationship (accessories)

Accessories
=============
PkAccessoryId  Fk_ProductId(Child)  ProductId(Parent)
---------------------------------------------------------
1                      2                1              (A has B As accessory)
2                      1                2              (B has A as accessory)  --(//this record is an invalid entry due to the missing constraint and need to prevent this.)
```

How to add a unique constraint for (Fk_ProductId, ProductId) so that combination of Fk_Productid and ProductId cannot be added.

```
Example: Invalid case as this will make a loop of accessory
         1,  2
         2   1
```

i have already added a constraint  as below.

```
ALTER TABLE Tx_ProductAccessories
  ADD CONSTRAINT UNI_CONS_Fk_ProductId_ProductId UNIQUE(Fk_ProductId, ProductId);
```

Also i am planning to prevent any illegal entry where it will cause a loop.
like below.

```
 A-A   (Read product A has product A as accessory )
 A-B-A
 A-B-C-A
 A-B-C-B
 ...
```

> Any product(P1) can be accessory of any other product(P2) as long as
>   the accessory product P1 is not a parent product, grand parent product
>   or anywhere in its Parents line which will cause a circular loop.

Comment: Write UDF function and add CheckConstraint? Or do checking in trigger

Comment: @lad2025 i am planning to add that.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the relationship between products and accessories.  You have both products and accessories in your products table, but no way to distinguish between them, so there's no way to determine which products are actually accessories and should not appear in the ProductID(parent) column.  Can all products also be accessories?  If so, you need some way to determine which pairings are valid.

Comment: @Beth yes any product can be accessory of any product, but no product  in its parent line can be added as an accessory of that product as this will make a loop.

Comment: How can you determine if product A can have accessory B or if product B can have accessory A?  Does the first entry win?  So if product B was entered with accessory A, you then would want to disallow product A associated with B?

Comment: @Beth yes the first entry wins. so its either A-B or B-A bit not the both entry at same time.

Comment: you might need a derived column, productChain, or allParts, containing the sequential list of items up to the parent node to determine where products and accessories overlap.  In your example, both accessoryIDs would have chains 1,2

Comment: so they can always enter whatever ID they want in the product(Parent) field, you want the limit applied on the product(child/accessory/part) field

Comment: What about siblings?  So if A has part B and part C, should B and C with each other be disallowed?

Comment: @Beth   no its valid.  A(B, C) and (either B-C or C-B ) as this is not making  a loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using computed columns:

```
alter table Tx_ProductAccessories
    add least_productId as (case when Fk_ProductId < ProductId
                                 then Fk_ProductId else ProductId end);

alter table Tx_ProductAccessories
    add greatest_productId as (case when Fk_ProductId < ProductId
                                    then ProductId else Fk_ProductId end);

alter table Tx_ProductAccessories
    add constraint uni_fkProductId_ProductId unique(least_productId, greatest_ProductId);
```

Comment: I like it. How would you extend it for more columns? Or textual data

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. But you still need an expression for the middle value. Would a hash of the three values be more or less efficient than a multi-column constraint? EDIT: Nevermind, I thought OP needed three columns.

Comment: Looks like it will work for the first case. I will try it.

Comment: @lad2025 . . . With more complicated expressions ;)  This is intended to answer the question as asked.

Comment: Can I assume that in general your solution is based on adding computed columns which are sorted and one unique for all computed columns?

Comment: @lad2025 . . . That is how this works for two columns.  Doing this on more than two columns in SQL Server is a pain.  If you have  a particular problem, then ask a question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I haven't any particular problem. I just wonder about generalizing it for collumns with the same type. Here is my **[trial](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b94c4/1/1)**

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Go ahead, ask the question ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff There will be no question. If you don't like to discuss with comments, just say it. When I see solution I always search for edge cases or how to generalize it. That's all.